# what does the field separator in awk do here?

Tags: awk

In this context, how does the specified field separator work?

```
awk -F\' '{print "conn kill "$2"\nrepair mailbox "$2" repair=1"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-F\'` is using the single quote `'` as the field separator.

Also the `'` is being escaped by preceding it with a `\` so that awk does not think of the `'` as the beginning of the action part.

Alternatively you can enclose the `'` in double quotes:

```
$ echo "foo'bar'baz" | awk -F\' '{print $1}'
foo
$ echo "foo'bar'baz" | awk -F"'" '{print $1}'
foo
```

Answer (score 1):

AWK processes a file line by line. And each line is separated into fields, that you can then access with the dollar variables `$1`...`$9` (`$0` is the whole line, IIRC). By default, the line is split into fields by using separating on whitespace, but you can specify on which character to split by using the `-F` command line option or the `FS` variable.

So in your case, the field separator is set to a single quote (`'`). An input line like `foo'bar'baz` will thus set `$1 == "foo"`, `$2 == "bar"` and `$3 == "baz"`.